# C# Mouse Click speed

Tags: c#, performance, click, mouse

Is it possible to remove the limit for the Mouse Click speed in C#?

Im trying to make a Click Game Programm. You have 15 seconds time to click on a Panel as fast as you can. Every click is a Point.

The Problem is... As example, when i click 10 times per second, I only get 5-6 Points per seconds and so I can't click as fast as I can.

Has somebody an idea to bypass this?

Thanks

Comment: It can be hardware based.

Comment: which event are you using?

Comment: I guess you're triggering doubleclicks. add a handler for those - does it fire? mousedown might work better. Add code to your post.

Comment: @dlatikay That's it. I used the Click Event. The MouseDown Event solved my Problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subscribe to the `Click` event, you will not see second clicks that occur in the doubleclick treshold, those are propagated to the `DoubleClick` event handler.

If you want to register clicks and bypass double click detection, subscribe to the `MouseDown` event instead.